# Converting CURL request to Wordpress wp_remote_post

Tags: php, curl, wordpress

I need to convert a PHP Library from CURL to wp_remote_post for use for a Wordpress Plugin.

I have reference the [Wordpress wp_remote_post page here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post).

This is the code I attempt to convert..

```
 $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $scheme . $url['host'] . $url['path']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->_config['UserAgent']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $response = "";
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        if ($response === false) {
            $errorResponse = curl_error($ch);
            require_once("FBAOutboundServiceMWS/Exception.php");
            curl_close($ch);

            throw new FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Exception(array(
                'Message' => $errorResponse,
                'ErrorType' => 'HTTP'
            ));
        }

        curl_close($ch);
```

This is what I 'thought' was correct but doesn't work...

```
$THEurl = $scheme . $url['host'] . $url['path'];
    $response = wp_remote_post( $THEurl, array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'timeout' => 45,
        'redirection' => 5,
        'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'blocking' => true,
        'headers' => array(),
        'body' => $query,
        'cookies' => array()
        )
    );

    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
       $errorResponse = $response->get_error_message();
            require_once("FBAOutboundServiceMWS/Exception.php");
            curl_close($ch);

            throw new FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Exception(array(
                'Message' => $errorResponse,
                'ErrorType' => 'HTTP'
            ));
    }
```

At what point does `wp_remote_post` actually get executed? Just when the function is called?
Many thanks for help in advance ;)

Comment: Do you have any error codes? Is anything showing in the error log? I cant see much wrong with what your doing. Whats within your `$query` variable? Also im not too sure why your running curl_close() in the error area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out for me and see what you get back

```
$THEurl = $scheme . $url['host'] . $url['path'];
$response = wp_remote_post( $THEurl, array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => 45,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking' => true,
    'headers' => array(),
    'body' => $query,
    'cookies' => array()
    )
);

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    $errorResponse = $response->get_error_message();
    require_once("FBAOutboundServiceMWS/Exception.php");

    throw new FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Exception(
        array(
            'Message' => $errorResponse,
            'ErrorType' => 'HTTP'
        )
    );
} else {
    echo 'Response:<pre>';
    print_r( $response );
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Took out the code you didn't need and also added in the printing of the response which you weren't doing before.

Comment: This led me to my answer, `wp_remote_post` returned my data in an array so I had to change the way the return answer was used. Thank for your assistance.

Comment: I found the inline documentation in the code more helpful than the docs pages for wp_remote_post etc.

https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.0.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-http.php#L149-L447