# convert curl post to wp_remote_post

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

Here is curl code which is working very good

```
$data = array(
        "to" => $to ,
        "from" =>  $options['from_email'] ,
        "subject" => $subject,
        "body" => $message,
 );
$url = 'https://example.com';
$api_key = 'apikeyhere'
              $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'X-API-KEY:'.$api_key
    ));         

   $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

But if i try to convert this above code to worpress wp_remote_post i am getting error.

```
 $response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
            'method'   => 'POST',
            'timeout'  => 45,
            'blocking' => true, 
            'sslverify' => false,
            'httpversion' => '1.0',
            'redirection' => 5,
            'headers' => array(
                'Accept: application/json',
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'X-API-KEY:'.$api_key
            ),
            'body'    => json_encode($data),
        ) );
```

here is response i am getting

https://pastebin.com/Ap5LpfZb

Please let me know where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you share more details about that error, and your attempts to resolve it?

Comment: 500 internal server error at response if i use wp_remote_post and if use curl it works :)

Comment: [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 500
            [message] => Internal Server Error
        )

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Ap5LpfZb

Comment: Does this help? Try adding `apikey` to the body attribute. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/319157/wp-remote-post-not-posting-data

Comment: You can see the above code is works if i use curl but not working at wp_remote_post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting CURL request to Wordpress wp\_remote\_post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763549/converting-curl-request-to-wordpress-wp-remote-post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it there was problem with the header array i was passing that array wrongly

Wrong code was

```
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
            'method'   => 'POST',
            'timeout'  => 45,
            'blocking' => true, 
            'sslverify' => false,
            'httpversion' => '1.0',
            'redirection' => 5,
            'headers' => array(
                'Accept: application/json',
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'X-API-KEY:'.$api_key
            ),
            'body'    => json_encode($data),
        ) );
```

Here is correct version of code

```
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
            'method'   => 'POST',
            'timeout'  => 45,
            'blocking' => true, 
            'sslverify' => false,
            'httpversion' => '1.0',
            'redirection' => 5,
            'headers' => array(
                'Accept'=> 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' =>'application/json',
                'X-API-KEY' => $api_key,
            ),
            'body'    => json_encode($data),
        ) );
```